# Proving two outer measures defined on the unit circle $C$ are the same measure.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Denote by $H^1(A)$ the 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now take $C$ to be the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now define an outer measure $\mathcal{H}$ on $C$ by
$$
\mathcal{H}(A):= \frac{1}{2\pi}H^1(A)
$$
Where $A \subset C$.

I am asked to prove that $\mathcal{H}$ is the **only** outer measure on $C$ which satisfies the following 3 conditions:

- $\mathcal{H}(C) = 1$.
- $\mathcal{H}$ is Borel regular.
- $\mathcal{H}$ is invariant under rotations.

I've already managed to prove that $\mathcal{H}$ satisfies the conditions but I'm having trouble with proving the uniqueness. That is, that there exists no other outer measure $\mathcal{M}$ on $C$ which also satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Maybe you can show them to be the same on 'intervals' with 'rational' endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure that satisfies the given conditions. Then $\mu$ is an honest measure when restricted to each open, half-open, or closed arc by regularity, and in particular, it is additive on these arcs. By translation-invariance and additivity, one may show that $\mu$ must assign to each arc of length $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ the measure $\frac{1}{n}$. By additivity, this implies that for any arc of length $\frac{2a\pi}{b}$ with $a,b\in \Bbb N$ and $a\leq b$, $\mu$ assigns this arc measure $\frac{a}{b}$.

From here, one can show that any open interval on $S^1$ must be mapped to it's length divided by $2\pi$ by $\mu$ by a least-upper-bound argument. Now you know the value of $\mu$ on a collection of subsets which generate the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets: this determines the measure, and in fact it must coincide with the given measure.

The reason it must coincide is that by regularity, every measurable set $A$ contains a Borel subset $B$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$. Since the value of $\mu$ on each arc is known, we may write $B$ in terms of the $\sigma$-algebra operations on the arcs, apply the measure to both sides of this relation, and then we get the value for $B$.

Comment: An outer measure is not necessarily additive.

Comment: The sets in question are measurable by the regularity, and an outer measure restricted to measurable sets is additive.

Comment: Ok. And by measurable you mean Carathéodory-measurable (by $\mu$)?

Comment: Yes, this is what Borel regularity means.

Comment: Well, the definitions are obviously not the same. As far as I know regularity means that I can approximate $\mu(S)$ for any Borel set $S$ by $\mu(U)$, where $U\supset S$ is open. At first sight, this  has nothing to do with Carathéodory-measurability.

Comment: The definition of Borel regularity is two things: every Borel set is measurable in the sense of Caratheodory and for every measurable set, we may find a subset which is Borel and has the same measure.

Comment: Auwww. Interesting. I didn't know there exists something like that. Thanks for clearing this up, KReiser.

Comment: Just to make things clear: @KReiser is saying that all measures are Carathéodory-measures when restricted to it's measurable sets? And since arcs are $\mu$-measurable then when taking a bunch of arcs, additivity is guaranteed?

Comment: Do you think you could go a bit deeper into the last claim? How does the value of $\mu$ on such subsets determine the measure?

Comment: By regularity, every set contains a Borel set of equal measure. Then, knowing the measure on a generating set for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra gives the measure for all Borel sets: write $B$ a Borel set as a complement/intersection/union of the generators, and then apply the measure to both sides.

Comment: Suppose two outer measures agree on the Borel sets, does that mean that they are equal on non measurable sets as well?

Comment: Yes, this is a classical construction in measure theory: see for instance Munroe's Method I & II from "Introduction to Measure and Integration", reproduced at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure or https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Outer_measure for instance.

Comment: @KReiser: I realise that the '$\inf$' construction of **an** outer measure will necessarily produce the same thing, I guess what I am asking is if the new outer measure created from the measure induced by an existing outer measure will be the same as the existing outer measure (excuse the longwinded question)...

Comment: Yes: denote $\mu$ a measure and $\mu^*$ the induced outer measure. For an arbitrary $A$, construct $B_i$ an at most countable disjoint union of open subsets $\{U_{i,j}\}_{j\in J}$ for each $i\in\Bbb N$ so $B_i\supset A$ and $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu(B_i)< \mu^*(A)+1/i$. Now $\bigcap B_i$ is a Borel set (thus measurable) and $\mu(B)=\mu^*(A)$.

Comment: @KReiser: Thanks!  I will blame my lack of caffeine.